Used powershell and Get-Content to subset a text file. Why is the output bigger than the original file?
I have a 25GB .sql file that is pure text. It is about 30k rows. Tried to slice it using the Get-Content command in powershell. I captured only the first 10k rows into a new .sql file - and the output was 45GB!
After re-trying the same but outputting into a .txt file, the output file was still 35GB - 10GB bigger than the original but 1/3 the rows.
What could be causing this and how can I actually achieve a file size reduction?

ASCII or UTF-8 input to UTF-32 output? Maybe look at a sample of the first 10-ish rows in each and see what's different.

I was indeed wondering about the encoding.. but why would one encoding versus another cause such a difference in file size?

Compare: [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetByteCount('A') with [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetByteCount('A'). You're probably using Out-File on PowerShell 5.1 and it defaults to unicode encoding doubling the size of your file cause of this. If you had used Set-Content you shouldn't experience this problem. cc @JoelCoehoorn

"why would one encoding versus another cause such a difference in file size?" Well, with ASCII or UTF-8, most characters are one byte. But with UTF-32, characters are always four bytes, a 4x increase in storage size. But more likely it's something in the middle.

You're probably using Out-File on Windows PowerShell 5.1 and it defaults to unicode encoding doubling the size of your file cause of this.
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetByteCount('A')    # 1
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetByteCount('A') # 2

If you had used Set-Content you shouldn't experience this problem, you shouldn't experience it either if you had chosen a different encoding.
Do note this issue is PowerShell 5.1 specific as in newer versions the default encoding for Out-File is utf8NoBOM.
$file = New-TemporaryFile
'A' * 1kb | Out-File $file.FullName
$file.Refresh()
$file.Length / 1kb # 2kb give or take
'A' * 1kb | Set-Content $file.FullName
$file.Refresh()
$file.Length / 1kb # 1kb give or take
$file.Delete()


i agree.. when I opened the file in Notepad++ I could see that it was UTF16, but the original was UTF8... so this might be the issue?

@Yoav24 that is the issue, yes

I see... this is the command I use on powershell to generate the file, is there an argument I can pass to make sure it generates the new file as UTF8?  "Get-Content -Path .\File1.txt -TotalCount 1000 > File2.txt"

@Yoav24 as explained in the answer if you're using powershell 5.1 don't use Out-File (> is exactly that), use Set-Content instead: Get-Content -Path .\File1.txt -TotalCount 1000 | Set-Content File2.txt

or, as alternative:  Get-Content -Path .\File1.txt -TotalCount 1000 | Out-File -Encoding utf8 -FilePath File2.txt. Note you can specify the encoding in Set-Content as well, should you ever need it.
